# Creating ID variable using digits from two different variables on SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to create a new variable on SAS. There is a column called "Statefip" and a column called "countyfip". I need a four digit ID number that combines these two columns.

For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq7Yf.png)

How do I tell SAS to follow this format when creating this new variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do using `put` and `input` statements. The `z3` format includes leading `0`'s in the output. `||` concatenates the `put` statements and then `input` converts the `id` field back to numeric.

```
data have;
input statefip countyfip;
    datalines;
1 1
8 109
12 57
13 313
;
run;

data want;
set have;
id = input(put(statefip,2.) || put(countyfip,z3.),8.);
run;

proc print;
```

Output:

```
Obs    statefip    countyfip      id

 1         1            1        1001
 2         8          109        8109
 3        12           57       12057
 4        13          313       13313
```

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you so much! Would this code work the same way for a huge data set i imported from a CVS file

Comment: Yes, it will work the same way as long as `statefip` and `countyfip` are imported as numeric variables. Good luck!

Comment: Also, if you don't mind me asking, what does the 2. in (statefip,2.) indicate?  and the 8. in (countyfip,z3.),8.); ?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: They are referring to to the format or length of the variable. If `statefip < 100` which I assume it is, then 2 is fine. Otherwise you can just increase the value. Changing the number after `z` changes the number of leading zeroes.

Comment: this code didn't work, it created new variable ID but that variable had no observations

Comment: @KiranKaur Make sure the input variables are numeric. You may want to increment the lengths depending on the length of the numbers. Also, try to run the code in sections and see where it's failing i.e. `var1 = put(statefip,2.); ` and `var2 = put(countyfip,z3.);`.